# How to initialize gluPerspective OpenGL projection type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, opengl, view

Now I initialize my OpenGL view by this code:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);               
glOrtho(0.0, w, 0.0, h, -1.0, 10.0);
```

And I it looks like it should look.
But its Othological view. And I want Perspective view. So I try to initialize that with:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);               
gluPerspective(60, w/h, 0.1, 100);
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
```

Comment: Why would you want that in perspective..?  Looks like you're making a 2D thing to me, so ortho would work fine.

Comment: I need to have possibility to move object on z axis (Zoom-IN / Zoom-OUT). And I need to be able to show full image in my app window (zoomed-out) and after editing to save it original size using `glReadpixels`.

Comment: You can move an object on the z axis in ortho and it would move as accordingly.  Unless you're going to rotate it and the perspective of the object is going to matter.

Comment: I'm going to make zoom-in zoom-out function, where image has to get smaller or bigger depending on position of z axis. As I know ortho can't do this thing. It's z axis as I know is used for items sorting (witch should be on top, witch under it and so on). If I'm wrong, correct me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your first misconception is thinking in terms of "initialization". OpenGL is a state machine and you're expected to set the state as required throughout your program. Those calls you call "initializing" actually belong into the drawing code.

Second: The projection matrix is sort of the "lens" of OpenGL, hence all sorts of projection belong there, and only there, which also applies to `gluPerspective` (which is not part of OpenGL but GLU, a third party library, that eventually calls `glFrustum`).

In your original code you set the ortho limits to the viewport size, i.e. you're going to see the world space coordinate rate (0,0) to (width,height). Everything in that worldspace volume will fill the view. In the case of perspective you got a viewing volume symmetrically centered around the Z axis and depending on the near and far planes will usually cover something like about (-near*aspect, -near) to (+near*aspect, near) at the near clipping plane. In your case that would be something like -0.1,-0.1 to 0.1,0.1, which is a very small volume and will just largely magnify your image.

How to fix this?

1. Understand how OpenGL works
2. Stop cargo cult programming, i.e. just copy and pasting code from tutorials into places that might look right, without really understanding what's going on.

Now in your case I strongly doubt you actually want perspective for that "Drop your image here" backdrop, but only for whatever is drawn on top of this. Remember that I told you OpenGL is a state machine? Well, here's why: Because you should switch projections between those two drawing stages:

1. draw your backdrop using a ortho projection
2. draw whatever else you want with a perspective projection on top.

Comment: Actually I written it by my own, not copied from tutorial. I readed pretty much information about otho and perspective projections, and I understand what difference is between them. I just don't understand correctly how perspective projection works, so I still don't know how to make it working. I'm learning. So I think its OK to do mistakes. Thank you for your answer. Now I'm trying to figure out everything. :)